# Regular Expression validator with file upload control (asp.net) does not work in FireFox

Tags: asp.net, regex, file-upload, validation, firefox3.6

I am using **Regular Expression validator** with **file upload** (Asp.Net) control in-order to restrict the files uploaded. My regular expression is as follows:

```
^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))+(.wmv|.avi|.mpeg|.MPEG|.mp4|.MP4|.flv|.f4v)$
```

It gives error message of the validator even after uploading the right file in Firefox. But it works fine in IE.

Any one please help me providing a browser compatible way to validate my file upload control.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of good and bad strings?  I can't tell what that regex is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

t does not work with Firefox v3.x because it does not allow JavaScript to get full path name from the file input field and this particular regular expression expects to see full path name.

Use javascript to do the validation instead of regular expression validator.

var fileName = fupID.value;
 var ext = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

```
        if (ext == "wmv" || ext == "WMV" || ext == "avi" || ext == "AVI" || ext == "mp4" || ext == "MP4" || ext == "flv" || ext == "FLV" || ext == "F4V" || ext == "f4v" || ext=="mpg" || ext=="MPG" || ext=="mpeg" || ext=="MPEG" || ext=="mov" || ext=="MOV") {
     // do required code logic here
```

}